# Creating UIImage from CIImage

Tags: ios5, uiimage, core-image

I am using some CoreImage filters to process an image. Applying the filter to my input image results in an output image called filterOutputImage of type CIImage.

I now wish to display that image, and tried doing:

```
self.modifiedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filterOutputImage];
self.photoImageView.image = self.modifiedPhoto;
```

The view however is blank - nothing is being displayed.

If I add logging statements that print out details about both filterOutputImage and self.modifiedPhoto, those logging statements are showing me that both those vars appear to contain legitimate image data: their size is being reported and the objects are not nil.

So after doing some Googling, I found a solution that requires going through a CGImage stage; vis:

```
CGImageRef outputImageRef = [context createCGImage:filterOutputImage fromRect:[filterOutputImage extent]];
self.modifiedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputImageRef scale:self.originalPhoto.scale orientation:self.originalPhoto.imageOrientation];
self.photoImageView.image = self.modifiedPhoto;
CGImageRelease(outputImageRef);
```

This second approach works: I am getting the correct image displayed in the view.

Can someone please explain to me why my first attempt failed? What am I doing wrong with the imageWithCIImage method that is resulting in an image that seems to exist but can't be displayed? Is it always necessary to "pass through" a CGImage stage in order to generate a UIImage from a CIImage?

Hoping someone can clear up my confusion :)

H.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that `self.photoImageView` is a UIImageView?  <s>If so, ultimately, it is going to call `-[UIImage CGImage]` on the UIImage and then pass that CGImage as the `contents` property of a CALayer.</s>

(See comments: my details were wrong)

Per the UIImage documentation for `-[UIImage CGImage]`:

```
If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the
value of the property is NULL.
```

So the UIImageView calls -CGImage, but that results in NULL, so nothing is displayed.

<s>I haven't tried this, but you could try making a custom UIView and then using UIImage's `-draw...` methods in `-[UIView drawRect:]` to draw the CIImage.</s>

Comment: Ahh! Thank you. Yes, the photoImageView is a UIImageView. I had no idea it used the CGImage property of the UIImage.

Comment: One more question, in which document is it explained how the UIImageView displays its image? I'm trying to find out where you learnt that from :)

Comment: Actually, now that I actually look at the binary code:  UIImageView overrides -drawRect: rather than calling setContents: on its own CALayer.  It looks like it ultimately calls into the UIImage draw methods, which grab the CGImageRef and draw it.  So, same result, but my details were wrong.

Comment: class-dump helps as well.  The presence of -[UIImageView drawRect:] was a huge hint to me that my original statement about contents was wrong

Answer (score 18):

This should do it!

```
-(UIImage*)makeUIImageFromCIImage:(CIImage*)ciImage
{
    self.cicontext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    // finally!
    UIImage * returnImage;

    CGImageRef processedCGImage = [self.cicontext createCGImage:ciImage 
                                                       fromRect:[ciImage extent]];

    returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:processedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(processedCGImage);

    return returnImage;
}
```